# Yo doesn't work on mac even after fixing path

Tags: node.js, macos, zsh, yo

I installed Yo million times and it never worked... I uninstalled node and reinstalled it, deleted npm folder, and still yo can't be found.

The error message I get is:

> zsh: command not found: yo

I updated path in bash_profile as follows:

```
    [[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM$

# added by Anaconda2 4.2.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/myusername/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

# added by Anaconda3 4.4.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/myusername/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

# added by Anaconda3 4.4.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/myusername/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

export PATH="/Users/myusername/npm/lib/:$PATH"

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

And updated bashrc file as follows:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

export GMAIL_USERNAME=“"
export GMAIL_PASSWORD=“”
export MAILCHIMP_API_KEY=""
export MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID=""
export OWNER_EMAIL=“"

export PATH=/Users/myusername/npm/bin:/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/$

export PATH=/Users/myusername/npm/bin:/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/$

export PATH=/Users/myusername/npm/lib

export PATH=/usr/local/bin
```

Node.js was installed at

/usr/local/bin/node

npm was installed at

/usr/local/bin/npm

Please help!!! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Zsh won't read your Bash environment files (unless you tell it to by
sourcing them; not recommended). Try making those `export` settings in
`~/.zshrc`.  You can `print` (or `echo`) them in Zsh to ensure they
took.

*(Note that you have some problematic characters in your listed files.
Hopefully it's just a paste issue, but I see curly quotes and some
stray `$`s.)*